# Grails not finding my resources

Tags: css, grails, gsp, url-mapping

My Grails project structure:

```
my-app/
    grails-app/
        <mostly typical grails-app structure>
        views/
            web/
                index.gsp
            app/
            admin/
            layouts/
                main.gsp
    <rest of project structure is like any other Grails app>
```

So you can see whereas, normally, the index page is located at `grails-app/views/index.gsp`, I have it at `grails-app/views/web/index.gsp`.

My `application.properties`:

```
app.grails.version=2.4.2
app.name=my-app
app.context=/
app.version=0.1
```

One section of my `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/"(view:"/web/index")
```

My `main.gsp` layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="MyApp"/></title>
    <g:resource dir="css" file="myapp.css" />
    <g:layoutHead/> 
</head>
<body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <g:resource dir="js" file="myapp.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

My `index.gsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When the app starts up and I view it in a browser, it is obvious that `myapp.css` is not being found because the page styling is all wrong. When I view page source I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>

    /css/myapp.css
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    /js/myapp.js
</body>
</html>
```

So it sounds like Grails takes your `app.context` and uses that as the prefix for all resources. And because I haven't wired something correctly, Grails is just translating my `<g:resource>` tags into plaintext and printing them out in the HTML.

I guess my question is: **What do I need to do so that Grails can find my CSS/JS resources?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't sure that tag into tag will be work correctly, so write like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css', file:'myapp.css')}" charset="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.6/ref/Tags/resource.html), The resources tag generates a link (URI) string. Can be used in an href, JavaScript, Ajax call, etc.

Use the resources tag inside script or link tags to get your css/js loaded in your page like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<g:resource dir="css" file="myapp.css" />" charset="utf-8"/>
```

You can also use [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources), which I would recommend as it solves the purpose and has good [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/)

Comment: The [Asset Pipeline](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) plugin has replaced resources as the main Grails solution for CSS and Javascript files. Personally I find it much better than the resources plugin.